# Problem running operations in dask after loading multiple csv files

Tags: python, csv, dataframe, dask

I am trying to start using dask for handling large data sets in some ML projects. Loading singular CSV files into a dask dataframe works fine. When i try to use multiple CSV files, any "compute" like operation causes the program to hang indefinitely.

This runs fine

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd
import dask
from dask.distributed import Client

client = Client(processes=False)
df = dd.read_csv('sftp://somestuff//4120109.csv')
shape = dask.delayed(print)(df.shape)
shape.compute()
```

Output: (3600, 3723)

The following code hangs indefinitely

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd
import dask
from dask.distributed import Client

client = Client(processes=False)
df = dd.read_csv('sftp://somestuff//412010*.csv')
shape = dask.delayed(print)(df.shape)
shape.compute()
```

It should load the 10 files that match and give a shape of (36000, 3273)
I know it hangs specifically on the shape.compute() line after putting in some choice print lines. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

You should not mix dask.delayed and dask.dataframe.  Probably you just wanted to call `dask.compute(df.shape)`

https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/delayed-best-practices.html#don-t-call-dask-delayed-on-other-dask-collections

Comment: Running the script still hangs, I completely forgot about map_partitions. I will try to see if it can work that way. Thanks for the info!